# Does async/await tasks executed sequentially or in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Here is the code that make 3 HTTP requests in underlying methods to get information either input PIN ID is existing in one of 3 products, which offer REST API for it.

It creates and awaits 3 tasks. I would like to double check either these tasks are executed in parallel or sequentially

```
public async Task<Product> IdentifyPin(TokenParams token, string pin)
{
        Task<ApiResponse<ProductInfo, ErrorData>> productATask = GetProductAInfo(ProductType.A, pin, token.JwtToken, true);
        Task<ApiResponse<ProductInfo, ErrorData>> productBTask = GetProductBInfo(ProductType.B, pin, token.JwtToken, true);
        Task<ApiResponse<ProductInfo, ErrorData>> productCTask = GetProdctCInfo(pin, token.JwtToken, true);

        ApiResponse<ProductInfo, ErrorData> productAInfoResponse = null;
        ApiResponse< ProductInfo, ErrorData> productBInfoResponse = null;
        ApiResponse< ProductInfo, ErrorData> productCInfoResponse = null;

        // await HTTP response from ProductA info endpoint
        try
        {
            productAInfoResponse = await productATask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log().Error(ex.Message, exception: ex);
        }

        // await HTTP response from ProductB info endpoint
        try
        {
            productBInfoResponse = await productBTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log().Error(ex.Message, exception: ex);
        }

        // await HTTP response from ProductC info endpoint
        try
        {
            productCInfoResponse = await productCTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log().Error(ex.Message, exception: ex);
        }

        // Mapping responses to new Product() and returning it
        // ...
}
```

Comment: I believe the tasks should be running in parallel, but will block sequentially on the awaits.

Comment: What happened when you actually ran the code?  Did they run in parallel, or in sequence?

Comment: You might want to consider Task.WhenAll()

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know anything about the inner workings of `GetProductAInfo`, all we can say is that there is nothing in your code to prohibit parallel processing of the three requests by the server.

Assuming that your `GetProductAInfo` is not doing anything grossly inefficient, all three requests would be active concurrently, and could proceed in parallel on the server.

Ultimately, it is up to the server to decide if the three requests should be processed in parallel, sequentially, or in some other way (e.g. throttled to no more than 2 active requests at a time).

**Note:** If you own `GetProductAInfo` API, consider renaming it to `GetProductAInfoAsync` to following C#'s naming convention for `async` methods.

Answer (score -3):

They will run in parallel, and as such the second and third may well have already completed when the first is awaited.

(It's also possible that one or more of the methods returns a task already completed, especially if they can e.g. check on a memoised value and only obtain it asynchronously when necessary).

Comment: "If they are not started then each await will start its task before waiting on it"  `await` can never possibly start a task.  It only ever adds a continuation to a task.

Comment: @Servy right you are. I rather confused myself by something I did recently that was awaiting unstarted tasks, but those were being started elsewhere, not by the `await`.